# Windows update 'You're not up to date' and 'Your device is missing important security and quality fixes' but no obvious errors

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-update, updates

Windows Update which has been working fine until today now says:

> You're not up to date
>
> Last checked: Today, 20:37
>
> Your device is missing important security and quality fixes.

I have:

```
Windows 10 Pro
Version 2004
Installed on 28/06/2020
OS build 19041.1415
Experience Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0
```

Optional updates lists the following:

```
- Windows updates
 - Feature update to Windows 10, version 21H2
- Driver updates, if you have a specific problem... (etc)
```

Update history shows lots of successful updates (none are failed).
The most recent update in the history is from today:

```
Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602
Successfully installed on ‎17/‎01/‎2022
```

I am not on a 'metered connection' (Ethernet LAN).
I have plenty of hard drive space.

I've tried the following:

- restart Windows (I've had update get stuck before and this has resolved issues previously)
- running troubleshooter for Windows update (no solutions)
- clearing the Windows update cache (stop Windows update service, delete contents of C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download then restart the service)

I noticed the log file C:\Windows\WindowsUpdate.log says 'Please run the Get-WindowsUpdateLog PowerShell command to convert ETW traces into a readable WindowsUpdate.log' - I did this - there are quite a few of these (9 in a row) in the converted log:

```
*FAILED* [80246007] ISusInternal:: IsCommitRequired
```

I also tried the following based on [this](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-windows-update-error-code-80246007)

```
net stop msiserver
net stop wuauserv
net stop bits
net stop cryptSvc
ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old (I got 'Access is denied' for this)
ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
net start wuauserv
net start cryptSvc
net start bits
net start msiserver
```

None of this seems to have helped.

I'd rather not install the feature update if possible. Any ideas what else to try?

Comment: Perhaps because you have tried so may things, now it is time to consider a Windows 10 Repair Install. Second link on the page I reference and use the option to Keep Everything.    https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Instead of an repair install use the Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant to perform the upgrade to 21H2 if that upgrade fails post the log from Setup Diag. You are running an unsupported version of Windows 10, hence the message, you are missing an update. [1415](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/december-14-2021-kb5008212-os-builds-19041-1415-19042-1415-19043-1415-and-19044-1415-b46200db-74c3-450e-b200-51013957312a) is the last update released for 2004. You have all available updates already installed

Comment: Thanks both, upgrading to 21H2 resolved the issue for me. TBH it wasn't clear to me before posting here that I was running an unsupported version - possibly I swatted a dialog / warning in the past, I don't use this machine daily...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrading to 21H2 resolved the issue.

Comment: I have had this update nuisance in a while until today, and have not bothered to solve it since it was not causing any issues/errors on my laptop. I simply stuck with the motto, "If a program works, don't touch it", which is quite the case for Windows. I have exactly the same version, OS build, etc. as you specified above. I am writing these words to vouch for that solution for whom needs it.

Comment: This one is correct, but the one below about using the Windows 10 Update Assistant is how you actually get to install the new version

Answer (score 3):

Use the Windows 10 Update Assistant to upgrade the version first:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

After that then updates should be available.